# The inclusion-exclusion principle for probability and counting.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I am wondering whether "The inclusion-exclusion principle" from chapter 8 (rosen textbook) is the same with "The inclusion-exclusion principle for probability and counting" ?